# SQL Server / SSISDB Jobs suddenly taking longer to complete

Tags: sql-server, performance, debugging, ssis, etl

Beginning on 12/29/2022, several of our SSISDB packages started taking twice as long to finish their etl. This delays the beginning of our daily reporting for our company.

There are no errors that give much of a clue, and there is nothing out of the ordinary in the logs. The company has been on a code deployment freeze for 3 weeks now, so I'm pretty sure it is not that.

The Server CPU fluctuates between 30 and 60%, so I don't think it's a server resource issue. This phenomenon is occurring to various ETLs. I have looked into the reasons while these jobs will "Hang" or go "Runaway", but there is no discernable explanation I can find.

Can you recommend steps for debugging? SQL Server Management Studio 2018.

Comment: What are the data sources for the packages - on another server or local to SQL?  If another server then it could be that, or network utilisation.

Comment: The data sources for this DW is coming from Oracle Instances. There is no indication that there has been any issues on that side(I only have read privileges there). The Server that this DW runs on only services this DW and the Multidimensional Cubes that run once all the ETL Jobs are finished. I spoke with our DB Admin and he hasn't seen any network errors or load issues for our server.  That's not to say there isn't an issue there. Many of these packages started taking longer at the same time. They aren't handling more data than usual.

Comment: Use the ssisdb, it will have logging events for all executed ssis packages. You can get idea of rows loaded and package times. Also look at the reports in the integration catalog

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the resolution is not very satisfying. After working on this issue for nearly a month one of the DB-admins pointed out that the server had not been restarted in nearly 2.5 months. So it was restarted and everything went back to normal.

Comment: I used to work with a guy who said server's should never need to be restarted.  Coming from a Software background I know that pretty much all Applications/OSes have memory leaks.  A restart every month is the minimum in my experience - weekly is better if you can fit it in.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).